# Java: Are this.foo() and super.foo() the same when foo() is in the super class?

Tags: java, this, extends, super

Say I have the following classes:

```
class Foo {
    protected void method() {}
}

class Bar extends Foo {

}
```

At this point, from the class Bar, I have access to `method()` in two ways:

- `super.method();`
- `this.method();`

From what I see, they seem to perform the same action. Is there a difference between these two in this context? Is there a preferred version to use if so?

Using `super` makes sense because `method()` is part of the super class. Using `this` makes sense too I suppose, as Bar will inherit the properties of the class Foo, and therefore `method()` as well, right?

Comment: In the situation you described, both variants have the same semantics. But normally, one uses `this` unless it is necessary to use `super`.

Comment: Alright, cool. I was under the impression that `super` was possibly preferred if the method isn't overridden, as to point to where it's defined.

Comment: Only use `this` if you must.  It hints that there is a reason for doing so, and that reason should be very clear.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, `this.foo()` calls the same method as `super.foo()`.

Note that there will be a difference if `foo()` is overridden in the child class. But in this case, it runs the same method implementation.

We use `super.foo()` when we need to specifically request that the superclass's method implementation be executed, when there's one available in the current class.

> Using super makes sense because method() is part of the super class

Yes, but remember that the child class can change at some point and get an overridden `foo()`, in which case `super.foo()` may start calling the unintended implementation.

This is something to be aware of. For this reason, calling `this.foo()`, or unqualified `foo()` may be justified.

Answer (score 12):

Just be aware that the child can be overridden yet again:

```
public class Main {
  static class Foo {
    protected void method() {
      System.out.println("Bye");
    }
  }

  static class Bar extends Foo {
    {
      this.method();
      super.method();
    }
  }

  static class Baz extends Bar {
    protected void method() {
      System.out.println("Hi");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Baz();
  }
}
```

Produces:

```
Hi
Bye
```

So, although `this.method()` and `super.method()` may behave the same in some cases, they do not produce the same byte-code.